# Excel Macro Runtime error '-2147417848 (80010108)': Method 'Copy' of 'Range' failed

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range

I have a macro that I am currently running on two different workbooks, however it is giving me the above error on one workbook only. Through trial and error, I'm learning that it's working when I am sorting smaller batches of data, but when I attempt to sort data (5000+), the workbook stops responding and gives me that error pop-up.

The purpose of the macro is to distribute data into different named tabs based off of the fourth column. The user selects the information they want to be sorted and the macro does the rest. Is there a better way to do this so that it can handle 10000+ rows of data?

```
Sub Disperse_Data()
      For Each myCell In Selection.Columns(4).Cells
        If myCell.Value = "400" Then
        myCell.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("SU400").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2)
    End If
Next
```

The Next triggers the next instance, where the value is a different number and the worksheet is a different name. Thank you all for your help!

I have tried rewriting the macro, copying the macro from the other workbook into this one, verifying all data is the proper data (numbers where numbers are expected, etc.) Each attempt had the same results. I was expecting/hoping for it to just work.

Comment: Try `myCell.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("SU400").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`

Comment: Maybe also fully qualify `Rows.Count`.

Comment: *worksheet is a different name* - how ?, `Worksheets("SU400")` is fixed. How many *different named tabs* are there ?

Comment: @CDP1802 There are 73 different named tabs.

Comment: Presumably there are 73 unique values in column D for the 10,000 rows of data, or are there values in column D that should be ignored ?

Comment: @CDP1802 Wanted to provide further clarification - The first instance would read `Worksheets("SU400")`. The next instance would read `Worksheets("SU401")`, and so on.

Comment: @CDP1802 There really only should be the 73 unique values, but in the event that these values are inputted incorrectly then in that case they would be ignored.

Comment: @TimWilliams I updated my macro with this script and had the same issue. No error message pop up, but Excel timed out, froze, and had to shut it down.  However, if I reduce the number of rows I select, it works perfectly.

Comment: @CLR By fully qualify, do you mean call out the row numbers? I apologize if that's a silly question - I'm still learning macros :)

Comment: Probably the most efficient way to do this is to use AutoFilter to filter the required rows, then copy and paste the visible rows to the relevant sheet in one operation.  That could be done in a loop using a single Sub.

Comment: Fully qualify = `myCell.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("SU400").Range("A" & Worksheets("SU400").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Autofilter

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Disperse_Data()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsData As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngData As Range, n As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim s As String, c As Long, r as Long
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    ' check selection
    If Selection.Column <> 4 Then
        MsgBox "Select column D", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf vbNo = MsgBox(Selection.Rows.Count & " rows selected, OK", _
        vbYesNo, "Confirm") Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set wsData = Selection.Parent
    With wsData
        Set rngData = Intersect(Selection, .UsedRange)
        ' last column
        c = .UsedRange.Column + .UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1
        'MsgBox rngData.Address & " " & c
    End With
    
    ' copy
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        If ws.Name Like "SU4##" Then
            s = Right(ws.Name, 3)
            'ws.Cells.Clear
            r = 1 + ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
            With rngData.Offset(, -3).Resize(, c)
                .AutoFilter 4, s
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                  ws.Range("A" & r)
                .AutoFilter
                n = n + 1
            End With
            ' remove header
            If ws.Range("D" & r) <> s Then ws.Rows(r).Delete
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox n & " sheets updated", vbInformation, _
           Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant! Thank you. I had a couple of questions, though - 

1. Regarding `If ws.Name Like "SU4###" Then` - the values in column D will include 4## to 6## . How do I adjust this macro to account for the 5## and 6##s?
2. When it disperses the data to the fixed tab names, it inputs the data starting at A1. On each individual tab rows A1 & A2 are header rows, labeling the data. I saw the "remove header" note section, but before I started playing with it I wanted to be sure that would be the area to do so.

Comment: @TimWilliams Reading that suggestion was like a literal light bulb turning on over my head. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @joey `If ws.Name Like "SU[456]##" Then`. If you have headers in rows 2 then the copy should be into row 3. The remove header section is to remove the any header copied from the selection.

Comment: This is absolutely perfect. Thank you so much for this and taking the time to explain the code a bit to me! I wish I could buy you a cup of coffee, haha.

Comment: @joey Not quite perfect :), I forgot the `Exit Sub` after `MsgBox "Select column D", vbCritical`.